# How can I have dashes on my ul li, when some of my li's have two lines (ipad)

Tags: css, ipad, list, html-lists

I'm working on the css / html for this ipad page.

[image]

Here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/KaWpZ/1/

What CSS do i need to use to get dashes? and why can't I make them align properly on so that the text on the second line (like Sport, eco, normal etc) sits padded and not underneath the dash.

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use the before pseudo tag for dashes: `ul li:before { content: "-"; }` or you can just use a small background image for the list bullets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an iPad you've got access to the `:before` pseudo-element, allowing you to use:

```
ul li{
    padding-left: 1em;
    position: relative; 
}

ul li:before {
    content: '-';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KaWpZ/3/)